# when the text in a textbox is equal to a certain word i need to value in the combo box to be saved for that text

Tags: vb.net

I have orders in text files in the debug folder and when i type the name of the order in a text box it displays the order is a list box and there is a combo box underneath where i can change the status of the meal preparation (Being prepared, ready to deliver etc,). If i go back to that form and type in the same order name into the textbox i need to previous prepartion status to be already in the textbox. Thanks for any help!

```
Public Class frmOrderStatus

    Private Sub btnStatus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStatus.Click
        Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(strTxtOrderNum & ".txt")
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            lstOrder.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
        Loop


    End Sub

    Private Sub OrderStatus_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstOrder.Items.Clear()
        btnStatus.Enabled = False
        ChangeStatus.Enabled = False



    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
        strTxtOrderNum = txtOrderNum2.Text
        btnStatus.Enabled = True
        ChangeStatus.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        strSaveStatus = ChangeStatus.SelectedIndex


    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeStatus.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you storing each order in a separate file?

Comment: yea each order is in a sererate file but when i'm trying to append the text in the textfile to add more text. The order opens in a list box but when i try to append the text it doesn't recognise the file name

Comment: This is the code im trying to use ```    Dim swVar As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText(strTxtOrderNum & ".txt")

        swVar.WriteLine(strSelectedItem)
        swVar.Close()```

Answer (score 0):

It recognizes the file; it just tells you it is in use. A Stream must be closed and disposed. I don't see the `StreamReader` even being closed let alone disposed. A `Using...End Using block will close and dispose of objects even if there is an error.

I just used a text file I happened to have to test.

```
Private strTxtOrderNum As String = "host"

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Using sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(strTxtOrderNum & ".txt")
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            ListBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub WriteFile()
    Dim strSelectedItem = ComboBox1.Text
    Using swVar As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText(strTxtOrderNum & ".txt")
        swVar.WriteLine(strSelectedItem)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks very much, had to completely change everything but got it working in the end